# How do I run the invalidateblock command on bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, block

For a particular need I need to restart with the chain from a specific previous block.

I thought about using the invalidateblock command, but it's a bitcoin-cli command and if I run it on bitcoind it replies with an error and doesn't execute it.

**How can I invalidate a block on bitcoind, or how can I restart from a specific block on bitcoind?**

Comment: What was the exact error message in full?

Comment: command not recognized. 
On bitcoind it just isn't recognized

Comment: There is no console in bitcoind, unlike in bitcoin-qt.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Which exact commands are you issuing? Exactly where and how do you issue those commands? What exactly are you seeing in response? Please update the question.